# Calling external API's in a Go+Gin project

Tags: rest, go

Im using `Gin` framework with `Golang` to create a Web App. I created some API's that can reach routes. I tested them in `Postman`, But how I can call inside my App? I have another `Go+Gin` project and I want to call those API's from there.

My question is that Gin has a mechanism to call Http requests, or I have to use Go's internal features? Im asking about Gin because it is better to use one approach for this things to have better code base. I searched but I can't find my answer. Gin has this feature?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this?